# How do I deploy an API into AWS API Gateway that has a dynamic link?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have deployed a microservice on AWS Elastic Beanstalk and the API is like this:

http://xyz-microservice.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/items/itemById/1 (This shows item 1)

http://xyz-microservice.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/items/itemById/2 (This shows item 2)

Notice this has a variable number which is the ID. How do I deploy this to AWS API Gateway? So far I can deploy only for one id but I want to deploy for all ids. Thanks.

Comment: no idea what you want. could you explain it further

Comment: So thing is so far I have found success in deploying an API endpoint for example for this partiuclar query: http://xyz-microservice.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/items/itemById/1. However, I want to create an endpoint for any ids through API gateway. Thanks.

Comment: You may want to look into proxy integration: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html